# CKEditor Drag and drop with Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, drag-and-drop, ckeditor, angular7

I would like to use the CKEditor and drag and drop with Angular 7. They do it with success on their site but I Can't seem to find any Angular solutions for this. As you see here:

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/draganddrop.html

But I have trouble converting this to Angular 7 component. My code is:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

@Component({
  selector: 'xxxx',
  templateUrl: 'xxxxx',
  styleUrls: ['xxxxx']
})
export class NyttInnholdComponent implements OnInit {

  public editor = ClassicEditor;

  public contacts = [];

  public model = {
        editorData: '<p>Tommy says, Hello!</p>'
    };

  constructor() { 
    this.contacts = [{
        name: 'Huckleberry Finn',
        tel: '+48 1345 234 235',
        email: 'h.finn@example.com',
        avatar: 'hfin'
      },
      {
        name: 'D\'Artagnan',
        tel: '+45 2345 234 235',
        email: 'dartagnan@example.com',
        avatar: 'dartagnan'
      },
      {
        name: 'Phileas Fogg',
        tel: '+44 3345 234 235',
        email: 'p.fogg@example.com',
        avatar: 'pfog'
      },
      {
        name: 'Alice',
        tel: '+20 4345 234 235',
        email: 'alice@example.com',
        avatar: 'alice'
      },
      {
        name: 'Little Red Riding Hood',
        tel: '+45 2345 234 235',
        email: 'lrrh@example.com',
        avatar: 'lrrh'
      }
    ];


  }

  ngOnInit() {
    //this.teswt ();
    this.editor.disableAutoInline = true;


    this.editor.plugins.add('hcard', {
      requires: 'widget',

      init: function(editor) {
        editor.widgets.add('hcard', {
          allowedContent: 'span(!h-card); a[href](!u-email,!p-name); span(!p-tel)',
          requiredContent: 'span(h-card)',
          pathName: 'hcard',

          upcast: function(el) {
            return el.name == 'span' && el.hasClass('h-card');
          }
        });

        // This feature does not have a button, so it needs to be registered manually.
        editor.addFeature(editor.widgets.registered.hcard);

        // Handle dropping a contact by transforming the contact object into HTML.
        // Note: All pasted and dropped content is handled in one event - editor#paste.
        editor.on('paste', function(evt) {
          var contact = evt.data.dataTransfer.getData('contact');
          if (!contact) {
            return;
          }

          evt.data.dataValue =
            '<span class="h-card">' +
            '<a href="mailto:' + contact.email + '" class="p-name u-email">' + contact.name + '</a>' +
            ' ' +
            '<span class="p-tel">' + contact.tel + '</span>' +
            '</span>';
        });
      }
    });

    this.editor.on('instanceReady', function() {
      // When an item in the contact list is dragged, copy its data into the drag and drop data transfer.
      // This data is later read by the editor#paste listener in the hcard plugin defined above.
      this.editor.document.getById('contactList').on('dragstart', function(evt) {
        // The target may be some element inside the draggable div (e.g. the image), so get the div.h-card.
        var target = evt.data.getTarget().getAscendant('div', true);

        // Initialization of the CKEditor data transfer facade is a necessary step to extend and unify native
        // browser capabilities. For instance, Internet Explorer does not support any other data type than 'text' and 'URL'.
        // Note: evt is an instance of CKEDITOR.dom.event, not a native event.
        this.editor.plugins.clipboard.initDragDataTransfer(evt);

        var dataTransfer = evt.data.dataTransfer;

        // Pass an object with contact details. Based on it, the editor#paste listener in the hcard plugin
        // will create the HTML code to be inserted into the editor. You could set 'text/html' here as well, but:
        // * It is a more elegant and logical solution that this logic is kept in the hcard plugin.
        // * You do not know now where the content will be dropped and the HTML to be inserted
        // might vary depending on the drop target.
        dataTransfer.setData('contact', this.contacts[target.data('contact')]);

        // You need to set some normal data types to backup values for two reasons:
        // * In some browsers this is necessary to enable drag and drop into text in the editor.
        // * The content may be dropped in another place than the editor.
        dataTransfer.setData('text/html', target.getText());

        // You can still access and use the native dataTransfer - e.g. to set the drag image.
        // Note: IEs do not support this method... :(.
        if (dataTransfer.$.setDragImage) {
          dataTransfer.$.setDragImage(target.findOne('img').$, 0, 0);
        }
      });
    });

    // Initialize the editor with the hcard plugin.
    this.editor.inline('editor1', {
      extraPlugins: 'hcard,sourcedialog,justify'
    });

  }

}
```

Used like this:

```
<ckeditor [(ngModel)]="model.editorData" [editor]="editor"></ckeditor>
```

If I try this the this.editor will not contain any of the properties I was expecting. Which you find here: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_editor-classic_classiceditor-ClassicEditor.html

So, anyone know how I can get Angular to work with Angular 7 and CKEditor?

Comment: not sure whether that's really possible/ practical to do with cdk-drag-and-drop. By default you drop items into cdkDropLists, but cdkDropLists look nothing like this editor. I would copy the same approach they use. Remember "javascript is valid typescript".

Comment: Note that you use CKEditor 5 and plugins and API for CKEditor 4. This just won't work.

Comment: Well, I know... now. But didn’t back then ;). I just had to call CKEditor 4 via CDN and some minor changes in the controller to get it to work. Too bad they don’t have a proper Angular 2+ solution for drag and drop. Now it’s a "hack".

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

1. Use a div instead of the Angular CKEditor control.
2. Binding your CKEditor to the built-in drop and dragover events.

**Option 1 -Use a div instead of the Angular CKEditor control.**

Your template would look something like this.

```
<div cols="10" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10" data-sample-short contenteditable="true" >
</div>
```

Then your typescript would look somethign like

```
  ngOnInit(): void {

    CKEDITOR.plugins.add('hcard', {
      requires: 'widget',

      init(editor): void {
        editor.widgets.add('hcard', {
          allowedContent: 'span(!h-card); a[href](!u-email,!p-name); span(!p-tel)',
          requiredContent: 'span(h-card)',
          pathName: 'hcard',

          upcast: (el) => {
            return el.name === 'span' && el.hasClass('h-card');
          }
        });

        // This feature does not have a button, so it needs to be registered manually.
        editor.addFeature(editor.widgets. registered.hcard);

        // Handle dropping a contact by transforming the contact object into HTML.
        // Note: All pasted and dropped content is handled in one event - editor#paste.
        editor.on('paste', (evt) => {
          const contact = evt.data.dataTransfer.getData('contact');
          if (!contact) {
            return;
          }

          evt.data.dataValue =
            '<span class="h-card">' +
            '<a href="mailto:' + contact.email + '" class="p-name u-email">' + contact.name + '</a>' +
            ' ' +
            '<span class="p-tel">' + contact.tel + '</span>' +
            '</span>';
        });
      }
    });

    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
      extraPlugins: 'hcard, sourcedialog',
        toolbar: [
          { name: 'basicstyles', items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic' ] },
          { name: 'clipboard', items: [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo' ] },
          { name: 'document', items: ['Source'] }
        ],
        allowedContent: true,
        fullPage: true,
        height: '500px'
    });

    CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', (event) => {
      // When an item in the contact list is dragged, copy its data into the drag and drop data transfer.
      // This data is later read by the editor#paste listener in the hcard plugin defined above.
      CKEDITOR.document.getById('contactList').on('dragstart', (evt) => {
        // The target may be some element inside the draggable div (e.g. the image), so get the div.h-card.
        const target = evt.data.getTarget().getAscendant('div', true);

        // Initialization of the CKEditor 4 data transfer facade is a necessary step to extend and unify native
        // browser capabilities. For instance, Internet Explorer does not support any other data type than 'text' and 'URL'.
        // Note: evt is an instance of CKEDITOR.dom.event, not a native event.
        CKEDITOR.plugins.clipboard.initDragDataTransfer(evt);

        const dataTransfer = evt.data.dataTransfer;

        // Pass an object with contact details. Based on it, the editor#paste listener in the hcard plugin
        // will create the HTML code to be inserted into the editor. You could set 'text/html' here as well, but:
        // * It is a more elegant and logical solution that this logic is kept in the hcard plugin.
        // * You do not know now where the content will be dropped and the HTML to be inserted
        // might vary depending on the drop target.
        dataTransfer.setData('contact', this.CONTACTS[target.data('contact')]);

        // You need to set some normal data types to backup values for two reasons:
        // * In some browsers this is necessary to enable drag and drop into text in the editor.
        // * The content may be dropped in another place than the editor.
        dataTransfer.setData('text/html', target.getText());

        // You can still access and use the native dataTransfer - e.g. to set the drag image.
        // Note: IEs do not support this method... :(.
        if (dataTransfer.$.setDragImage) {
          dataTransfer.$.setDragImage(target.findOne('img').$, 0, 0);
        }
      });

    });
  }
```

Source code (Angular 10): https://github.com/steve-giles/ckeditorApp

**Option 2 - Binding your CKEditor to the built-in drop and dragover events.**

The problem with this approach is that you can only perform drag and drop in source view.

Your template would look something like this.

```
<ckeditor [(ngModel)]="model.editorData" [editor]="editor" (drop)="drop($event)"
          (dragover)="allowDrop($event)"></ckeditor>
```

Then in your typescript add the code for drop and drag where "text" is a reference to the element your dragging.

```
  allowDrop(ev): void {
    ev.preventDefault();
  }

  drag(ev): void {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData('text', ev.target.id);
  }
```

Finally add code to update the CKEditor with your text.  In this example I'm using "getElementById" but a better approach would be to use Angular binding.  Note that for this to work, the user needs to set focus in the editor to where the element will be dropped.

```
  drop(ev): void {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    var newValue = document.getElementById(data).textContent;

    var startPos = ev.target.selectionStart;
    var endPos = ev.target.selectionEnd;

    ev.target.value = ev.target.value.substring(0, startPos)
      + newValue 
      + ev.target.value.substring(endPos, ev.target.value.length);
  }
```

Source code (Angular 10): https://github.com/steve-giles/draganddrop

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Angular 7 and CKEditor5 and a Custom Directive.
You can create a Drag Directive and "drag and drop" data onto the Editor Document.

See the below for an example of a Drag Directive:
https://threeventures.com/build-html-drag-drop-angular/
https://github.com/ThreeVenturesTechnology/angular-drag-and-drop

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of work around and document search. The easiest way to drag and drop the external text/html that I have achieved using Ckeditor5 decoupled document editor and Angular 10. The example below and reference link [Where are the editor.insertHtml() and editor.insertText() methods? How to insert some content?](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/faq.html#where-are-the-editorinserthtml-and-editorinserttext-methods-how-to-insert-some-content)

app.module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CKEditorModule } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, CKEditorModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as DecoupledEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  public Editor = DecoupledEditor;
  editorInstance;
  public data = {
    editorData: '<p>Hello, world!</p>',
  };

  fieldMap: Map<string, string> = new Map<string, string>([
    ['studentFirstName', '{{ student.firstName }}'],
    ['studentLastName', '{{ student.lastName }}'],
    ['courseName', '{{ course.name }}'],
    ['courseHours', '{{ course.hours }}'],
  ]);

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  public onReady(editor) {
    editor.ui
      .getEditableElement()
      .parentElement.insertBefore(
        editor.ui.view.toolbar.element,
        editor.ui.getEditableElement()
      );
    this.editorInstance = editor;
  }

  allowDrop(ev): void {
    ev.preventDefault();
  }

  drag(ev): void {
    console.log('drage', ev.target);
    ev.dataTransfer.setData('dragElement', ev.target.id);
  }

  drop(ev): void {
    ev.preventDefault();
    const data = ev.dataTransfer.getData('dragElement');
    const dataValue = this.fieldMap.get(data);
    const viewFragment = this.editorInstance.data.processor.toView(dataValue);
    const modelFragment = this.editorInstance.data.toModel(viewFragment);
    this.editorInstance.model.insertContent(modelFragment);
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<ckeditor [editor]="Editor"  [data]="data.editorData" (ready)="onReady($event)"
          (drop)="drop($event)"
          (dragover)="allowDrop($event)">
</ckeditor>

Student
<ul>
  <li id="studentFirstName" draggable="true" (dragstart)="drag($event)">First name</li>
  <li id="studentLastName" draggable="true" (dragstart)="drag($event)">Last name</li>
</ul>

Course
<ul>
  <li id="courseName" draggable="true" (dragstart)="drag($event)">Name</li>
  <li id="courseHours" draggable="true" (dragstart)="drag($event)">Hours</li>
</ul>
```